# c++: записать в строку через stream

Tags: c++, строки, потоки-данных, stl

Подскажите, как можно в строку разместить вывод:

```
std::string line;
line << "a" << value << std::endl;
```

а потом ещё сравнить `line` и `line_old` например

я потом буду записывать `line` в файл или выводить на экран, но для начала мне хочется строку сравнивать и обработать, но очень не хочется формировать строку через `sprintf`

Comment: 1. += 2. ostringstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
ostringstream sline;
sline << "a" << value << std::endl;

cout << sline.str() << endl;
```

Ну т.е. ваша строка возвращается как `sline.str()`.

В одну строку - что-то вроде

```
cout << dynamic_cast<ostringstream&>(ostringstream() << "a" << 5 << endl).str();
```

но мне кажется, что это уже на грани фола...

Comment: а в 1 строчку никак нельзя, чтобы например sline объявить константой

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.